# Typescript Narrowing for Arrow Functions Inconsistent With Regular Variables

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

Simplified Examples:

Variable type narrowing

```
let a: string | number | boolean;
let b: string = '';
a = b;
```

This works and there are no warnings. However, if the example were:

```
let a: (arg: string | number | boolean, record) => boolean;
let b: (arg: string, record) => boolean = (arg, record) => record.name.indexOf(arg) === 0;
a = b;
```

This results in a warning `Type '(arg: string) => any' is not assignable to type '(arg: string | number | boolean) => any'.`

I'm wondering why this is since b's type requrement is a subset of a's.

In practice, there's a React library I'm using and a component's prop requires an anonymous function with `a`'s signature but I need to use `b`'s signature otherwise `indexOf` will complain. How do I make the narrowing behavior of functions behave similarly to the variable's?

Thanks.

Comment: Erm, why would the function be assignable here? A function that takes `string | number | boolean` should be callable with either. However, a function that only takes *one* of these defintely cannot be callable with either. Consider `x => x.charCodeAt(0)` - that function can *only* be called with a string. So, if you assign it to something that will be called as `fn(true)` or `fn(42)` then you'd get an error. Because those are not strings. The function is thus not callable with `string | number | boolean` as an argument.

Comment: obligatory: [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covariance-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc)

Comment: Functions are *contravariant* in their argument types for reasons of type safety, as mentioned in the comments and the linked questions/answers.